# question about java formula to describe a variable

Tags: java

i want t0 set a variable to let agent random get a number between 1-10(later use the number to filter people), but how could i set the formula for random variable? i use Random.next Int(1)+ 5; but error says :Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method next Int(int) from the type Random.
could you please help me? really a emergency

Comment: Please read [mre].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method fxn(int) from the type Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491750/cannot-make-a-static-reference-to-the-non-static-method-fxnint-from-the-type-t)

Answer (score 0):

You need a Random object.

```
Random rand = new Random();//Create random object
int randomInt = rand.nextInt(10)+1;
```

This is central to java in general. Non-static methods are attached to an object rather than a class, which is why you need to create an object to use them.

Comment: thanks so much for replying!! but error shows Random cannot be resolved to a variable. is there something i miss?

Comment: You need `import java.util.Random;` at the top of the program, after package

Comment: it has import java.util.Random, i checked the java source, after package

Comment: I think you must have mixed up `rand` and `Random` somewhere. `rand` is the name of the `Random` object. Can you try copying exactly from the answer to see if it works? The resulting number will be in `randomInt`.

Comment: x=new Random();
int randomInt = x.nextInt(11); i type like this, and error says  Cannot invoke nextInt(int) on the primitive type int. cannot convert from Random to int.