# How do I get the variable of one method to be a variable in another method for Java?

Tags: java

Here I am trying to have my 'cash' variable from the Player method be included in an equation in my wagerBet() method. Currently Eclipse is telling me that variable 'cash' cannot 'make a static reference to the non-static field cash'. I tried looking for explanations as to what this problem means but I'm just getting explanations that use even more programming terminology I don't understand being that I'm a rookie at this stuff.

```
class Player {
    private ArrayList<Card>hand;
    private double cash, bet;

    public Player(double theCash)
    {
        cash = theCash; //'cash' variable here
        hand = new ArrayList<Card>();
    }

    public static double wagerBet()
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Wager a bet: "); 
        double bet = in.nextDouble();
        cash = cash - bet; // needs to be transferred here
        System.out.println("You wagered " + bet + ". " + "Now you have " + cash + " cash left.");
        return bet;
    }

    public void rewardBet(double bet)
    {
        cash = cash + (bet * 2); //cash and bet variable needs to be transferred here as well
        System.out.println("You now have " + cash + "cash.");
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [cannot make a static reference to the non-static field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101585/cannot-make-a-static-reference-to-the-non-static-field)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cash` variable doesn't belong to any method. It is an instance member of the class. You can't access it from a static method. Make the method non-static, or pass 'cash' to it as a parameter if you only need to read its value there.

Comment: That fixes the problem for transferring the cash variables over to the 2 methods but my rewardBet() method still doesn't transfer over the bet variable from the wagerBet() method. Would I have to change anything about wagerBet() in order to make it accept the output of another method?

Comment: What do you mean by 'transfer over'? It returns it as a value. You just need to store the result when you call it.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to go through some Java basics:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html

You are attempting to use a property of Player in a static method. A static method is not part of an instance so it doesn't know what "cash" (as it's unique to every Player instance rather than a single variable).

Remove the "static" from wagerBet so that it becomes a method of Player. That way it's unique to every Player and so it'll know to use the "cash" of the same Player it's a part of.

Answer (score 0):

remove static at

```
public static double wagerBet()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is only one real problem. To understand what `static` is.

Basic approach, until you are good enough, is to NOT use `static` at all. Remove it in all cases instead of "main" (you have to keep it there).